# OpenCV:NetBeans:undefined reference to cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans-7, ubuntu-11.10

I am using NetBeans 7.0.1 to develop C++ applications using OpenCV 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.  When I try to build the application I get the following link error messages.

```
undefined reference to `cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D(CvRect, CvMemStorage*)'
undefined reference to `cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(CvSubdiv2D*, cv::Point_<int>)'
```

I have linked to the following libraries.

```
libopencv_calib3d_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_calib3d.so
libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4
libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.0
libopencv_contrib_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_contrib.so
libopencv_contrib.so.2.4
libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.0
libopencv_core_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_core.so
libopencv_core.so.2.4
libopencv_core.so.2.4.0
libopencv_features2d_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_features2d.so
libopencv_features2d.so.2.4
libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.0
libopencv_flann_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_flann.so
libopencv_flann.so.2.4
libopencv_flann.so.2.4.0
libopencv_gpu_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_gpu.so
libopencv_gpu.so.2.4
libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.0
libopencv_haartraining_engine.a
libopencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_highgui.so
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.0
libopencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_imgproc.so
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.0
libopencv_legacy_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_legacy.so
libopencv_legacy.so.2.4
libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.0
libopencv_ml_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_ml.so
libopencv_ml.so.2.4
libopencv_ml.so.2.4.0
libopencv_nonfree_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_nonfree.so
libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4
libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.0
libopencv_objdetect_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_objdetect.so
libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4
libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.0
libopencv_perf_calib3d_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_features2d_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_gpu_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_highgui_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_imgproc_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_nonfree_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_objdetect_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_photo_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_stitching_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_perf_video_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_photo_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_photo.so
libopencv_photo.so.2.4
libopencv_photo.so.2.4.0
libopencv_stitching_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_stitching.so
libopencv_stitching.so.2.4
libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.0
libopencv_test_calib3d_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_contrib_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_features2d_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_highgui_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_imgproc_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_legacy_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_ml_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_nonfree_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_objdetect_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_photo_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_stitching_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_test_video_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_ts_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_ts.so
libopencv_ts.so.2.4
libopencv_ts.so.2.4.0
libopencv_video_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_video.so
libopencv_video.so.2.4
libopencv_video.so.2.4.0
libopencv_videostab_pch_dephelp.a
libopencv_videostab.so
libopencv_videostab.so.2.4
libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.0
libraries.txt
```

I would be most grateful is someone could tell me how to resolve this error.

Many thanks in advance,
Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.4.0, `cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert` is in **libopencv_legacy.so**, and so should `cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D` according to the source code, but the latest wasn't found in the library compiled on Mac OS X.

To verify this info, go to OpenCV libraries directory and execute `nm`. If the result appears with the letter T before the symbol name it means that's the library that implements the symbol:

```
$ nm libopencv_legacy.so | grep cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert    
00000000000b5200 T _cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert
```

If you can't find `cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D` using this trick, consider [filing](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) a bug.

Comment: I got:<br> 0011a9be r _ZZ24cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsertE8__func__<br>
000d95b0 T cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert<br> but still get<br>undefined reference to `cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(CvSubdiv2D*, cv::Point_<int>)'when I add all the libraries in the directory.<br><br>Thanks,<br>Peter.

Comment: I have the same problem, this might be a bug. I suggest you report this issue to the OpenCV folks.